Values of NCRYPT_REQUIRE_VBS_FLAG and NCRYPT_PREFER_VBS_FLAG
I'm developing app which uses the Windows Cryptography API: Next Generation. Function NCryptOpenKey have some flags and I can't find the values for two of them:
NCRYPT_REQUIRE_VBS_FLAG = ?
NCRYPT_PREFER_VBS_FLAG = ?
Is anybody knows it's values or where I can find it?
I've tried to find it in Windows App SDK, in Google but unsuccessfull.

Header ncrypt.h

Are you looking for the actual value? In most cases you should steer away from such implementation details. If you write code that counts on them, that code will break if the value ever changes.

ncrypt.h doesn't contains the values for this flags. Yes, I need the actual values. It should be a part of Windows SDK but I haven't found it. Of course I'll update it in case of changing in the future.
